# Convergent sequence in a metric space is bounded

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I'm aware there a lot of questions of this type - I'm asking specifically whether or not the proof I describe is correct (which from what I can see has not been asked before), not for a general proof.

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence which converges to a point $x$ in a metric space $(X,d)$. So given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $$d(x_n,x)\leq \epsilon$$ for all $n\geq N$.

Set $$r={\rm sup}\{d(x,x_j):j\in\mathbb{N} \}+1$$

Then $\{ x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is contained in the ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$. Hence the sequence is bounded.

Comment: Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a convergent sequence instead of bounded. Now, to be more detailed you could explain more why $r$ is bounded

Comment: Consider $ X = \{1,\dots, N-1\}$. Why would it be $d(x,x_i)<r$ for any $i\in X$?